# Как на java определить ширину и высоту экрана телефона?

Tags: java, android, экран

Как на java программно определить ширину и высоту экрана телефона?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

Или так

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

Запрос в гугл: [android get screen size](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20get%20screen%20size&es_th=1)
Ответ по первой же ссылке

Answer (score 5):

Я так определяю:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
```

Answer (score 3):

В книге Дейтелов по разработке на андроиде (третье издание) я встретил такой пример:

// Определение размера экрана

```
int screenSize =
        getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout &
        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;
```

Правда это размер по специальной шкале класса Configuration: в диапазоне [1; 4], чему соответствуют константы с наименованиями: SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL, SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL, SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE и SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE.
Соответственно, это позволяет компактно использовать результат в логических выражениях, например так:

mUsedTwoFragmentLayout = screenSize == 4;

*Это не совсем то, что вам нужно, но я думаю, это будет полезно.*