Адаптивные activity под экран телефона
как сделать, что бы activity менялась в зависимости от размера экрана?
например если разрешение телефона меньше 1650x720, то будет включаться другая activity?
Пробовал делать папку res/layout-small, но она не применяет activity, указанные там
Есть ли способ распределить activity, именно что бы ограничивалось разрешением?(как в примере выше)

возможно я не правильно создавал папки или нужно что то еще включить. Я делал так: просто создавал директорию, например layout-small и копировал туда activity, затем изменял ее под размер

Указанный размер - это никак не small. 480 x 640 dp - это large. 720 x 960 dp - xlarge. (См. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources?hl=ru)

@iramm, указанный размер(1650x720) - это normal. И проблема в том, что разрешение выше (у меня это 2400x1080), тоже запускает normal. Поэтому и спрашиваю как их возможно разделить?

Наверное, нужно программно определить размеры экрана (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458873/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0-java-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0/620750#620750). И в зависимости от результата подставить подходящий макет.

Можно сделать разную разметку в зависимости от размера экрана, но активность будет эта же, что логично.
